# inserting a node at tail python

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm trying to insert a node at the tail but my list keeps just saving the last value

If I try to insert 1,5,7 at the head and 9 at tail..I only see 9 when I print it out

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val,next=None)
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

head = None

def insert(val, pos = 'h')
    global head
    if head == None:
        newNode = Node(val)
        newNode.next = None
        head = newNode
    elif pos == 'h':
        newNode = Node(val)
        newNode.next = head
        head = newNode
    elif pos == 't':
        newNode = Node(val)
        newNode.next = None

        #stuck here
        while(head != None):
            head = head.next
        head = newNode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a tail node, use a copy of head and when you reach the tail node, add the new node to it's '.next':

```
 # stuck here
    tail = head
    while(tail.next is not None):
        tail = tail.next
    tail.next = newNode
```

In your example, you change the global value of head to point to the new node you just added.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors here I think. One is you're replacing the global head (which needs to stay the same if you're adding at the tail). Use a local variable for the loop. Second is you're replacing the head itself by the new node instead of its .next field.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a no connection between head and tails. Change yours code like this.

```
  elif pos == 't':
        newNode = Node(val)
        head.next = newNode
        newNode.next = None
```

and you can remove below part

```
#stuck here
        while(head != None):
            head = head.next
        head = newNode
```

Answer (score 0):

There are just so many things about your implementation which are not recommended/frowned upon. For instance, you don't need to use a global variable for head.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
    self.next = None

def insert_head(head, val):
  node = Node(val)
  node.next = head
  head = node
  return head

def insert_tail(head, val):
  if head is None:
    return Node(val)
  head.next = insert_tail(head.next, val)
  return head

head = insert_head(None, 1)
head = insert_head(head, 5)
head = insert_head(head, 7)
head = insert_tail(head, 9)
```

Here's an implementation for example which provides the same functionality. To insert at head we simply create a new Node with the given value, point it's next element to the object pointed by head and then make head point to this node instead.

For inserting at tail we use an elegant recursive implementation. Both functions work even when the `head` node provided is `None`.

Why separate into two functions? Because typically you want your function to just perform a single well defined task. If a function is getting too complex you should break it down into smaller functions (again which do one thing and do it well). Newcomers often write functions with complex behaviors depending on some argument provided but that doesn't help with the readability, debugging, or performance of the function for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next


head = None


def insert(val, pos='h'):
    global head
    if head is None:
        newNode = Node(val)
        newNode.next = None
        head = newNode
    elif pos == 'h':
        newNode = Node(val)
        newNode.next = head
        head = newNode
    elif pos == 't':
        newNode = Node(val)
        head.next = newNode
        newNode.next = None
```